# Error fetching website source-code

Tags: android, url, httpwebrequest

I am trying to create a simple Android app that will have the possibility to fetch the source code of a website. Anyways, I have written the following:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
try {
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());          
    InputStream input = (InputStream) new URL(url.toString()).getContent();
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", "<html><body><p>"+input.toString()+"</p></body></html>", "text/html", Encoding.UTF_8.toString(),""); 
    setContentView(webView);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Alert alert = new Alert(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error fetching data", e.getMessage());
}
```

I've tried to change the 3rd line several times to other methods that will fetch the source code, but they all redirect me to the alert (error with no message, only the title).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a particular reason why you can't just use this to load the webpage?

```
webView.loadUrl("www.example.com");
```

If you really want to grab the source code into a string so you can manipulate it and display it as you are trying to do, try opening a stream to the content and then using standard java methods to read in the data to a String, to which you can then do whatever you want:

```
InputStream is = new URL("www.example.com").openStream();

InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(in);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);
String read = br.readLine();

while(read != null) {
    sb.append(read);
    read = br.readLine();
}

String sourceCodeString = sb.toString();
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("www.example.com/", "<html><body><p>"+sourceCodeString+"</p></body></html>", "text/html", Encoding.UTF_8.toString(),"about:blank");
```

Comment: It still alerts "Error fetching data"... (I want to show the web page source code, and have it as a string in run-time so I could perform more tasks with it)

Comment: What is the actual Exception thrown? If you post the e.getMessage() string, we can probably figure it out. Also, I think you should add a first and last argument to loadDataWithBaseURL so that all of the correct paths can be resolved. I have updated my answer to include this

Comment: 1) The e.getMessage() is empty when the "error" occurs.
2) I don't want to show the example.com website, but rather it's source code, just presented in the webView (for ease of functionality).

Comment: 1. That's very strange that the message is empty. Can you step through on the debugger and examine the exception to get more information? 2. I understand, in that case you can leave the first argument blank and you should be fine.

Comment: How can I step through the debugger? (Plus I have a problem with my s3 that it disconnects quite often, and becomes unrecognized).

Comment: If you're using Eclipse you just run the correct project from the drop down menu that looks like a little bug at the top of the window. First make sure to set a break point though. Here's some more info, although it's not that much: [Dubugging from Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-projects.html) As for your s3 disconnecting, thats a bummer. Try updating your drivers or trying a different usb cable. I had a phone recently that kept disconnecting and eventually I realized it was a bad usb cable.